# Facing error Cannot access rows from a non-nested table item when using varrays in plsql stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am a beginner in plsql and I am trying to write a procedure which counts the no of records present in a table and puts the result in another table. Now there are multiple tables I want to do this for so I put those in a varray but I am facing the above mentioned error

```
Create Or Replace Procedure count
AS
type arr IS VARRAY(5) OF VARCHAR2(30);
tables arr :=arr('tb1','tb2','tb3','tb4','tb5');
cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
   FOR i in 1 .. tables.COUNT
   LOOP
    select Count(*) INTO cnt from tables(i);
    insert into tb6 VALUES(tables(i),cnt);
    END LOOP
END;
```

Comment: You have `VAUES` not `VALUES`., `END LOOP` is missing a `;` statement terminator. Also, `COUNT` is a built-in function and you should call it something different.

Comment: That was just a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need **dynamic SQL** for that.

Here's how: a few sample tables (based on Scott's `emp` table), and `tb6` which will contain the result:

```
SQL> create table tb6 (val varchar2(10), cnt number);

Table created.

SQL> create table tb1 as select * from emp where deptno = 10;

Table created.

SQL> create table tb2 as select * from emp where deptno = 20;

Table created.

SQL> create table tb3 as select * from emp where deptno = 30;

Table created.
```

Which result do I expect?

```
SQL> select deptno, count(*) from emp group by deptno order by deptno;

    DEPTNO   COUNT(*)
---------- ----------
        10          3
        20          5
        30          6
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_count as
  2    type   arr is varray(5) of varchar2(30);
  3    tables arr := arr('tb1', 'tb2', 'tb3');
  4    cnt    number;
  5  begin
  6     for i in 1 .. tables.count loop
  7       execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || tables(i) into cnt;
  8       insert into tb6 values(tables(i), cnt);
  9     end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec p_count;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from tb6;

VAL               CNT
---------- ----------
tb1                 3
tb2                 5
tb3                 6

SQL>
```

As you can see, `tb6` contents matches expected values.

Comment: Thanks for the help, just wanted to ask if its advisable to use dynamic sql as in will it have a huge performance penalty?

Comment: You're welcome. As of dynamic SQL: use it, if you must. You could've done the same using several separate queries so ... it is up to you to decide which path you'll follow. For such a simple dynamic statements, I'd say that this is a simpler approach, easy to maintain. For complex dynamic statements - which are difficult to write, debug and maintain, it's worth to think about a different approach.

Comment: Yes exactly this seems like a simpler approach because I was only testing this in reality I have over 50 tables I need to do this for so that would mean writing similar sql queries over 50 times if static sql is used